# c++ reading with cin using previously read variable immediately

Tags: c++, c++11

somewhere in my code for some online judge I have the following:

```
vector<int> arr(1 << 20);

int p;
cin >> p >> arr[p];
```

this gives me a segmentation fault when compiled with judge's (I don't have access to their machine though) compiler g++ 4.9.2 but not on my local `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)`

however writing it as:

```
int p;
cin >> p;
cin >> arr[p];
```

works fine on the *judge* as well. Is this a known thing/bug? And why doesn't the first version work as expected?

Comment: Hoping for a clear answer on that, but there is no sequence point in `cin >> p >> arr[p]` that enforces that evaluation of `arr[p]` happens after the evaluation of `p` or `( cin >> p )`. Undefined behaviour, I think.

Answer (score 16):

Your first code, thanks to operator overloading, is equivalent to :

```
operator >> (operator >> (std::cin, p), arr[p]);
```

The evaluation of the function arguments `operator >> (std::cin, p)` and `arr[p]` is unsequenced. As you try to read *and* write `p` in unsequenced order, you get undefined behaviour.

What's probably happening is that your implementation, on this particular instance, evaluates arguments left-to-right, but the judge's one evaluates right-to-left, and indexes `arr` with an uninitialized `p`.